# Are args and args[..] the same?

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

I'm reading [optparse.coffee](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/optparse.html), and confused with the following line:

`args = args[..]`

What does that line do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#slices):

> **Array Slicing and Splicing with Ranges**
>
> Ranges can also be used to extract slices of arrays. With two dots (3..6), the range is inclusive (`3, 4, 5, 6`); with three dots (`3...6`), the range excludes the end (`3, 4, 5`). Slices indices have useful defaults. An omitted first index defaults to zero and an omitted second index defaults to the size of the array.

So saying `array[..]` is shorthand for:

```
len = array.length
array[0 .. len]
```

and that just makes a shallow copy of `array`. That means that `args = args[..]` just makes a local shallow copy of `args` so that `args` can be manipulated and changed without altering the original array that was passed in and you can store references to the array without the function's caller being able to accidentally alter your array through the original `args` reference that was passed to the function.

Consider this simplified example:

```
f = (args) -> args = args[..]
```

that becomes this JavaScript:

```
var f;

f = function(args) {
  return args = args.slice(0);
};
```

And [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

> Returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array.
>   [...]
>   If `end` is omitted, slice extracts to the end of the sequence.

So saying `array.slice(n)` returns a shallow copy of `array` starting at index `n` and going to the end of `array` and since arrays are indexed starting at zero, `array.slice(0)` makes a shallow copy of the entire array.